# How do I tokenize a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a string:

```
'"Apples" AND "Bananas" OR "Gala Melon"'
```

I would like to convert this to an array

```
arr = ['"Apples"', 'AND', '"Bananas"', 'OR', '"Gala Melon"']
```

I don't know if I can do it with a regular expression. I'm beginning to think I may have to parse each character at a time to match the double quotes.

Comment: Search for "JavaScript CSV parser" - it seems to be quite the same format

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript code to parse CSV data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8493195/1048572 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/1293147/1048572 and replace commata with spaces

Comment: @Bergi it's not the spaces.. it's not the same thing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
input = '"Apples" AND "Bananas" OR "Gala Melon"'

output = input.match(/\w+|"[^"]+"/g)
// output = ['"Apples"', 'AND', '"Bananas"', 'OR', '"Gala Melon"']
```

Explanation for the regex:

`/` - start of regex
  `\w+` - sequence of word characters
  `|`   - or
  `"[^"]+"` - anything quoted (assuming no escaped quotes)
  `/g` - end of regex, global flag (perform multiple matches)

Comment: I'd broaden the `\w` to `\S` or even a `[^ ]`

Comment: @Bergi that won't do. The character class cannot contain `"`, otherwise `"Gala` would match. `[^\s"]` would do.