# node.js: Convert json array to csv

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I want to convert a json array of elements to csv in node.js. I've found some module doing that like json2csv or json-csv but they are not complete. For example json2csv only support a flat structure where fields are direct children of the json root and also the schema should be the same for all json objects.
In my case, I want that. 
I suppose that i've a json array of objects like that:

```
[{
    "libelle" : "Projet 1",
    "beneficiaire" : "Mr Leroy",
    "nature" : "Diagnostics patrimoniaux",
    "phasage" : "GLOBAL",
    "budget": [
        {"status": "BROUILLON"}
    ],
    "status" : "BROUILLON"
},
{
    "libelle" : "Projet 2",
    "beneficiaire" : "Mr Leroy",
    "nature" : "Diagnostics patrimoniaux",
    "phasage" : "GLOBAL",
    "status" : "BROUILLON"
}]
```

and i want to convert it to csv like that:

```
"libelle","beneficiaire","nature","phasage","budget[0].status","status"
"Projet 1","Mr Leroy","Diagnostics patrimoniaux","GLOBAL","BROUILLON","BROUILLON"
"Projet 2","Mr Leroy","Diagnostics patrimoniaux","GLOBAL",,"BROUILLON"
```

I'm looking for a good and complete node module for doing that. If it doesn't exist, I will do it myself i think so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js

Look at this ling may help you

Comment: I've seen that and it's not what i want. Your link convert csv to json and me i want the reverse operation.

Comment: Can you use PHP for this ?

Comment: No I can't just node (javascript)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the module `jsonexport` its pretty easy, check this sample:

**Sample:**

```
var jsonexport = require('jsonexport');

var contacts = [{
   name: 'Bob',
   lastname: 'Smith',
   family: {
       name: 'Peter',
       type: 'Father'
   }
},{
   name: 'James',
   lastname: 'David',
   family:{
       name: 'Julie',
       type: 'Mother'
   }
},{
   name: 'Robert',
   lastname: 'Miller',
   family: null,
   location: [1231,3214,4214]
},{
   name: 'David',
   lastname: 'Martin',
   nickname: 'dmartin'
}];

jsonexport(contacts,function(err, csv){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(csv);
});
```

**The ouput:**

```
lastname;name;family.type;family.name;nickname;location
Smith;Bob;Father;Peter;;
David;James;Mother;Julie;;
Miller;Robert;;;;1231,3214,4214
Martin;David;;;dmartin;
```

**Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonexport**

Comment: Can it be used in TypeScript environment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are a few npm modules, like [fast-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-csv) and [ya-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ya-csv), that are very helpful for this.

```
var csv = require('ya-csv');
var fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
```