# How to format CSV to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, csv

Below is the CSV - input file

Id  Type    SubType Input   Accounts
196 ListenToMusic   StereoReceiver  DVD 22
196 ListenToMusic   StereoReceiver  GAME    19
196 PlayGame    StereoReceiver  Game    2404
196 PlayGame    StereoReceiver  DVD 831

Expected Output as image,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5eTf.jpg

Comment: What does your app look like? Where are you trying to do this. i.e. client/server? Can you share the code you currently have?

Comment: I am trying to convert CSV to JSON using node.js. But i stuck with the complex format. Could you please help me?

Comment: There's a whole load of packages that should be able to help you out with this. csvtojson - https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson for example. There's an example of it being used here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js

Comment: I already tried with that option but its not giving me the output what i expect. Hence i am looking for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your back problem is that CSV is row column format.

ex
Name,Address,Phone
Al Smith,111 Main Street,(555) 121 - 1234,
...
Jenny Jones,1891 Apple Ave,(333) 345 - 8765

Your in data is hierarchical

From you example: 
DVD,GAME
22,19
2401,831

is a valid CSV file.   File conversion does not create information and your final data destination has more information (in the form relationship hierarchy) than your starting data