# Node.JS / Express.JS : Convert properly data from CSV file to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv, express

I'm intending to load data **from a CSV file** and send it within Express Router **as JSON data**.

**My CSV looks like this :**

- There is **no headers** ,
- my delimiter of lines is simply the **"/n"** ,
- and my values are under **" "**

  "2171106","2017-07-03 00:27:24","France","3","Desktop","Mac","Firefox","2170248","77.98"
  "800309","2017-07-03 03:23:21","France","9","Desktop","GNU/Linux","Safari","2170296","85.39"
  "805789","2017-07-03 03:34:32","France","1","Tablet","iOS","Mobile Safari","2170299","61.49"
  "2171167","2017-07-03 04:42:47","France","1","Desktop","Windows","Chrome","2170314","39.99"
  "2171170","2017-07-03 04:50:02","France","1","Desktop","Windows","Chrome","2170320","20.89"
  "838601","2017-07-03 05:48:38","France","1","Smartphone","iOS","Mobile Safari","2170323","66.88"
  "2171173","2017-07-03 06:09:28","France","1","Desktop","Windows","Microsoft Edge","2170407","57.77"
  "1659566","2017-07-03 06:28:08","France","1","Smartphone","Android","Chrome Mobile","2170416","32.99"
  "835619","2017-07-03 06:46:00","France","4","Desktop","Windows","Firefox","2170419","203.93"
  "773872","2017-07-03 06:51:14","France","8","Tablet","iOS","Mobile Safari","2170422","285.79"
  "2171241","2017-07-03 06:54:30","France","1","Desktop","Mac","Safari","2170425","29.49"
  "2171238","2017-07-03 07:02:48","France","1","Desktop","Windows","Firefox","2170434","49.95"
  "1570588","2017-07-03 07:08:09","France","1","Desktop","Windows","Microsoft Edge","2170437","61.06"
  "2111374","2017-07-03 07:08:21","United Kingdom","1","Tablet","iOS","Mobile Safari","2170440","36.58"
  "1604941","2017-07-03 07:18:38","France","2","Tablet","iOS","Mobile Safari","2170452","30.89"
  "2095884","2017-07-03 07:25:34","France","1","Tablet","iOS","Mobile Safari","2170458","65.79"
  "2171259","2017-07-03 07:26:48","France","1","Desktop","Windows","Firefox","2170461","62.67"
  "860366","2017-07-03 07:30:46","France","1","Desktop","Windows","Chrome","2170464","137.67"

And to show it better , here is it :

[image]
i wanna just parse this data to an object , and send it within express as json .

i have used several libraries : **csvjson , csvtojson , papaparse** ...
but something goes wrong with the conversion every time.

**Here is my server code:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
var fs = require('fs');
var Converter  = require("csvtojson").Converter;

var fileStream = fs.createReadStream("data.csv");
var jsonData;
//new converter instance
var converter = new Converter({constructResult:true});

//end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished
converter.on("end_parsed", function (jsonObj) {
    jsonData = jsonObj
});
fileStream.pipe(converter);

app.get("/list",function(req,res){
    res.json(jsonData);
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Running at Port 3000");
```

When running , the conversion goes wrong , it displays data like this :
[image]

As you can see , it's completely wrong :
here is for example the first outputed element :
[image]
Almost libraries are converting it in the same wrong way , i think that there is a **missing config** in my code . **(tabulations sperataing lines maybe)**

**Any suggestions ??**

Comment: Can you describe exactly what is wrong with it?  Is it just that hte labels are wrong?

Comment: you need to install the package csvtojson with simple npm install --save csvtojson@latest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js

Comment: @Legman : i ve added a snapshot of an example of wrong converted data

Comment: @headmax same problem

Comment: Try to convert online your CSV to show if the result and put to a validator json http://www.csvjson.com/csv2json  https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the csvtojson API docs:

noheader:Indicating csv data has no header row and first row is data row. Default is false.

So maybe in your Converter construct add noheader:true.