# Node.js convert csv file to json formate

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, csv

I am beginner to programming. I am reading the csv data from the file then I need to convert csv data into json formate.
This is my csv data file:

```
batch_id  ingredient_code   quantity    expiry_date
1             item1           1000      18-01-2019
1             item2           500       18-02-2019
2             item1           1000      18-01-2019
3             item2           1000      18-08-2019
4             item2           1000      18-01-2019
4             item1           1000      18-05-2019
4             item3           500       18-04-2019
5             item4           1000      18-01-2019
```

I am expecting output like this

```
[{
   batch_id : 1,
   items :[{ingredient_code:item1, quantity:1000, expiry_date:18-01-2019},
           {ingredient_code:item2, quantity:500, expiry_date:18-02-2019}]     
   },
   {
     batch_id : 2,
     items :[{ingredient_code:item1, quantity:1000, expiry_date:18-01-2019}]     
    },
    {
      batch_id : 3,
      items :[{ingredient_code:item1, quantity:1000, expiry_date:18-01-2019}]     
    },
    {
      batch_id : 4,
      items :[{ingredient_code:item1, quantity:1000, expiry_date:18-05-2019},
              {ingredient_code:item2, quantity:1000, expiry_date:18-01-2019},
              {ingredient_code:item3, quantity:500, expiry_date:18-04-2019}]     
     },
    {
      batch_id : 5,
      items :[{ingredient_code:item4, quantity:1000, expiry_date:18-01-2019}]     
}]
```

what I am expecting is batch id should display single time, all the items of that batch id should be added to array.
thanks in advance.....
sorry for poor english

Comment: Go through https://stackoverflow.com/a/17190385/5995973

Comment: SO is not a code provider. You should first propose a code that you already tried and tell use what are you expecting from this and why it doesn't match your needs. To start with your problem, you can find tutorials to read a CSV file, then how to store the data from a CSV file

Answer (score 2):

Csv file is in same location as js file,Install node module **csvtojson**

```
var csv = require("csvtojson");
csv().fromFile('a.csv').on("json",function(jsonArrayObj){ 
     console.log(jsonArrayObj); 
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty map.
2. Iterate over data line by line.
3. Split each line by comma.
4. Use batch id as key and look for it in map, it exists, push data into array otherwise initialize that key with an array containing data for that row.
5. Iterate over keys and create an array out of it.

Comment: thank you for your response, can you please give some example.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive it by installing the **csvtojson** in your node module, by typing the following command:

**npm install csvtojson --save**

You can get more detailed information here [from-csv-file-to-json-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#from-csv-file-to-json-array).

Answer (score 0):

**2 Steps Process:**

1) Run `npm i -g csvtojson` in terminal.

2) Run `csvtojson source.csv > converted.json` in terminal where your file located. Note that "source.csv" is the file that you want to convert and "converted.json" is the file that you will generate.

For documentation, see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#command-line-usage)