# when using csv-parser from csv module to convert a csv file to json, how do I get the headers as key pairs in the json output?

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying something like the following, but this doesn't work

```js
const parser = parse(req.file, {
  headers: true
})
// Use the readable stream api
parser.on('data', function(csvrow) {
  console.log(csvrow);
})
```

Comment: [have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js)

Comment: for anyone who comes to this in the future, if you scroll down in the link @Dohab provies, the answer is there. thanks dohab!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
parse(sampleFile, {columns: true}, function(err, data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
    });
```