# How to convert Csv to Json using Node.js?

Tags: json

```
var csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json');
var fileInputName = 'Bangalore_schools.csv'; 
var fileOutputName = 'output.json';
csvToJson.generateJsonFileFromCsv(fileInputName, fileOutputName);
```

Csv File Link: [Csv File](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openbangalore/bangalore/master/bangalore/Education/Bangalore_preschools.csv)

But the above code i have used i am unable to fully convert it to json. Please help. Output is coming like this.. i want to separate each key and its value likewise we have in json.

```
[
 {
  "district|block|cluster|schoolid|schoolname|category|gender|medium_of_inst|address|area|pincode|landmark|identification1|busroutes|identification2|latlong": "-----------+---------+----------------------------+----------+-------------------------------------------+---------------+--------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------"
 },
 {
  "district|block|cluster|schoolid|schoolname|category|gender|medium_of_inst|address|area|pincode|landmark|identification1|busroutes|identification2|latlong": " bangalore|south-1|vajara halli|32868|GKHPS ALAHALLI|Upper Primary|co-ed|kannada|avalahalli south range- 1|bangalore|560062|masjid||||POINT(77.5766623020172 12.8893003120716)"
 },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert CSV to JSON in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js)

Comment: *"As default the filed [sic] delimiter is the **semicolon** (`;`)."* You should read the docs for the library you're using. I'd also consider looking for a more mature library if you're going to rely on it for app functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The default delimiter `convert-csv-to-json` uses is a semicolon (`;`). If you want to use a different delimiter, like `|` the file you shared uses, you need to define it explicitly. E.g.:

```
csvToJson.fieldDelimiter('|').generateJsonFileFromCsv(fileInputName, fileOutputName);
```