# return value is not working outside the function?

Tags: node.js, node-csv-parse

when we console.log(restaurantdata) inside the .on('end') function return log but outside function log  cant give value return undefined.

```
    var restaurantdata=[];
    fs.createReadStream('restaurantsa9126b3.csv')  
    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (data) => restaurantdata.push(data))  
    .on('end', () => {
        return restaurantdata; 

      }) 
      console.log(restaurantdata);
      yield this.render('home',{
        restaurantdata:restaurantdata,
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your CSV data and what is your expectation from your code?

Comment: I want my csv data to JSON formate

Comment: It looks duplicate .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js

Comment: Did you check the link for the solution? Also, your shared file ( we need access to check it), better paste few lines here in the question.

Comment: ok i'll provide

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_oxQUmLMM1h9TdaGiOA7Q18ev03-KKc_/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

```
function convert(data) {
    data = data.split('\n');
    var heading = data[0].split(',');
    var arr = [];
    var line,words,err;
    for(var i=1;i<data.length-1 ;++i){
        var obj = {};
        line=data[i];
        words = line.split(',');
        var k =0;
        for(var j=0;j<words.length;++j){
            if (words[j].indexOf('\"')==-1){
                obj[heading[k]] = words[j];
                k++;
            } else{
                err = [];
                err.push(words[j].substring(1,words[j].length));
                j++;
                while (words[j].indexOf('\"')==-1) {
                    err.push(words[j]); j++;
                }
                err.push(words[j].substring(0,words[j].length-1));
                obj[heading[k]] = err;
                k++;
            }
        }
        arr.push(obj);
    }
   return arr;
}
```

Hope, This may help you...