# Convert CSV Array To JSON NodeJS

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, csv

I am scraping data from a `URL` containing a `csv`. The format of the data I'm scraping is like this:

I am doing this in `Node.js` and using the nodejs-`requestify package`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/requestify

When I console the `response.getBody()` it's in the exact same format as the screenshot provided.

I am trying to convert this to a `JSON array` that I can iterate over in a loop to insert the values into a database, however, am struggling to get the data into `JSON` format.

I've tried splitting the array in multiple ways (`comma, single quote, double quote`). I've tried `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` (and both in combination).

Here is the code I'm using. Ultimately when I `console.log` rows in the loop, this is where it should be in `JSON` format, however, it's just coming in as comma separated values still.

```
requestify.get('URL').then(function(response) {
  // Get the response body
  var dataBody = response.getBody();
  var lineArray = dataBody.split('\r\n');
  var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(lineArray));

  for(var s = 0; s < data.length; s++) {
    var rows = data[s];
    console.log(rows)
  }
});
```

Comment: In general it's not safe to assume that splitting on line breaks will give you the rows of a CSV. With quoted fields a line break can appear within a field. I strongly recommend using an existing CSV module like [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) or [csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) which will handle the edge cases for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert CSV to JSON in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831250/how-to-convert-csv-to-json-in-node-js)

Comment: OK I will look into csv-parse

Comment: So the lineArray gives you the value you have shown in the image ? 
One more thing is you are doing JSON.stringify the JSON.parse which is not correct.

Comment: I solved this. Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using `csvtojson` and `aws-dsk` since my csv is hosted on S3.

```
async function startAWS(db){
  //Retrieve AWS IAM credentials for the 'master' user
  var awsCredentials;
  try{ 
    awsCredentials = await retrievePromise(config.get('aws')); 
  }
  catch (e) { 
    console.log({error:e},'startAWS error'); 
  }
  //Setup the AWS config to access our S3 bucket
  AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
    accessKeyId :  awsCredentials.principal,
    secretAccessKey :awsCredentials.credential,
    region:'us-east-1'
  });
  //Call S3 and specify bucket and file name
  const S3 = new AWS.S3();
  const params = {
    Bucket: '***',
    Key: '***' //filename
  };
  //Convert csv file to JSON
  async function csvToJSON() {
  // get csv file and create stream
  const stream = S3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
  // convert csv file (stream) to JSON format data
  const json = await csv().fromStream(stream);

  //connect to DB and continue script
  db.getConnection()
  .then(async (conn) => {
    if(json.length) {
      for(var s = 0; s < json.length; s++) {
        var rows = json[s];

        const insert = await conn.query(
          'SQL HERE'
        );
      }
    }
  })
  };
  csvToJSON();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a basic misundertanding I think

```
var lineArray = dataBody.split('\r\n');
```

lineArray now contains something like

```
"a", "b", "c"
```

but for doing something like

```
var data = JSON.parse(lineArray);
```

you need lineArray to be

```
{ "a":"1", "b":"2", "c":"3" }
```

I think you need something like

```
const lineData = lineArray.split(',');
const keys = ["name", "age", "gender"];
const jsonLineData = {};
keys.forEach((key, index) => {
    jsonLineData[key] = lineData(index);
});
```

Comment: To confirm, in the keys array I put the headers of my csv?

Comment: This did not work for me. Maybe you can elaborate on this code?