# Read CSV file with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, csv

I need to read then contents of a CSV file from the local server. In my CSV file I have three fields, those are:

- Region,
- Acct_Name,
- State.

while getting the values in Acct_Name values are in the format of comma. In my CSV file reader it is separating comma and that value is going to state.

So how can I solve that issue?

My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // AJAX in the data file
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
        });

    // Let's process the data from the data file
    function processData(data) {
        var table = $("<table />");
                    var rows = data.split(/\r\n|\n/);
                    for (var i = 1; i < rows.length-1; i++) {
                        var row = $("<tr />");
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");

                        for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
                            var cell = $("<td />");
                            cell.html(cells[j]);
                            row.append(cell);
                        }

                          var usedNames = {};
                            $("select[name='company1'] > option").each(function () {
                                if(usedNames[this.text]) {

                                    $(this).remove();
                                } else {
                                    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
                                }
                            });
                              $("select[name='company2'] > option").each(function () {
                                if(usedNames[this.text]) {

                                    $(this).remove();
                                } else {
                                    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
                                }
                            });
                                $("select[name='company3'] > option").each(function () {
                                if(usedNames[this.text]) {

                                    $(this).remove();
                                } else {
                                    usedNames[this.text] = this.value;
                                }
                            });
                            $("#region").append("<option value =1> " + cells[0] + " </option>");
                            $("#state").append("<option value =1> " + cells[1] + "</option>");
                            $("#accname").append("<option value =1>" + cells[2] + "</option>");

                        table.append(row);
                    }

    }
});
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Also, you should change dataType to `text/csv`

Comment: i have changed the data type but not working

Comment: And you're not getting any errors in the console?

Comment: ya i am not getting any errors i am thinking                          var cells = rows[i].split(","); is splitting the cell values that is the problem

Comment: No errors in console at all? That sounds kinda odd. What happens if you do console.log(data)? Does it show the content of the CSV file?

Comment: ya i am getting the csv data in the console and i showing that data into the corresponding fields also but the problem is Acct_Name field is containing the comma so that  var cells = rows[i].split(","); this line is splitting and the value of Acct_Name is going to the state field

Comment: You might want to use a CSV library, if you want to use a delimiter for those fields. It's not something you *just* do.

Comment: i need some solution can u pls send me mail id i wil forward my whole code to u pls it is urgent

Comment: Nope I cannot help you further. Look into delimiters.

Comment: @panduk check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript

Comment: Who produces the `CSV` and how? Can you make changes to it?