# Reading one line at a time with an XmlHttpResponse object

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am coding in JavaScript, and I am using AJAX to open up a file. It opens up the file fine, and I can read the file. But it is a comma separated file with many lines. The problem is that the .responseText property of that object covers ALL of the text within the file.

What I need is for it to give it to me one line at a time, so I can split the records and process the file accordingly.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I parse a CSV string with Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To split a string on line breaks, use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var lines = str.split('\n');
```

Since you mentioned your file is comma separated, you can then get each of the values by using `split(',')`:

```
lines.forEach(function(line) {
  var values = line.split(',');
  // do stuff
});
```