# Using javascript to read a csv txt file and load results into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I'm trying to use javascript to read a txt file with the contents in a CSV format, parse through it and load it into a single array so I can do math operations to it like (sum, average, standard deviation). I got as far as reading the textfile and I need help with parsing through it.

Thanks!

inputExample.txt

```
5,4,4,4,4
3,3,3,3,2
1,5,4,7,6
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="openFile" />
    <br>
    <pre id="fileContents"></pre>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
document.getElementById("openFile").addEventListener('change', function(){
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(){
        // document.getElementById("fileContents").textContent = this.result;
        console.log(this.result);


    }
    fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12289296/1743938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = this.result.split(',');
```

If your content is also separated by new lines as your example you could replace them with commas and then split them.

```
var arr = this.result.replace(/\n/g, ',').split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common question. You can use regular expression or string operations.

This one uses regular expression:

```
 // I am assuming your file has newline and carriage return, depending on your file format, it may have either of them or both of them
 var foo = "5,4,4,4,4\n\r3,3,3,3,2\n\r1,5,4,7,6";
 var regex = /(\d)(?=,|\n\r?)?/g;
 var arr = foo.match(regex);
 console.log(arr); //[ '5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '2', '1', '5', '4', '7' ]
```

And this one uses string operation:

```
 var foo = "5,4,4,4,4\n\r3,3,3,3,2\n\r1,5,4,7,6";
 var arr = [];
 foo = foo.split('\n\r').forEach(function(el){
     el = el.split(',').forEach(x => arr.push(x));
 });
 console.log(arr); //[ '5', '4', '4', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3', '3', '2', '1', '5', '4', '7', '6' ]
```

Check this link about how to parse csv in detail.

[How can I parse a CSV string with Javascript, which contains comma in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)