# Javascript: How to change string formated value into to array?

Tags: javascript

I would like to convert string formatted text into an array as follows. Source string is like:

```
var myString = "[3, 8750, "Some text, with commas"]";
```

Required result is as follows:

```
myArray[0] = 3;
myArray[1] = 8750;
myArray[2] = "Some text, with commas";
```

I will appreciate any kind of support..

Comment: Looks like it's just JSON.  So use JSON.Parse?

Comment: That is not a valid string. Check your quotes and correct please.

Comment: `JSON.parse(myString)`, but fix your string format first (*ex: make the outer quotes single*).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse a CSV string with Javascript, which contains comma in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)

Comment: On the backend side, I didn't defined it as JSON, but an ordinary array.. Anyway thanks for your quick support

Comment: @Tolga An ordinary array with primitive values is a valid JSON value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()` to change string formated value into to array.

```js
var myString = "[3, 8750, \"Some text, with commas\"]";
let myStringList =JSON.parse(myString);
console.log(myStringList);
```