# How to Preprocess CSV column inputs in Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: javascript, jquery, mechanicalturk

I am currently trying to create an Amazon Mechanical Turk HIIT from their website and modifying the HTML/JS code.

I have a CSV file with a column called content. In each HIIT, I want to split the value of this column (a string) based on a delimiter. I also know that the input to the CSV is inside the HTML in the below form.

```
${content}
```

How can I access the content column input from inside Javascript, so I can do things like `content.split(";")` and render `div`s looping over the list of splitted sentences?

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data