# Parsing CSV content with Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I searched and tried many solutions including [papa parser](https://www.papaparse.com/) in angular and functions offered in the [related Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)...no luck. I always have a problem with fields which contain comma.

CSV file structure is like this: (export from **Numbers**)

```
name; address
Jack; 762 Texas Rd, Morganville NJ 07751 USA
```

...but I know that ";" or "," would have been a possible delimiter.

In papa, I tried to set delimiter '', so I expect papa parser to find the delimiter itself.

```
this.papa.parse(csv_content,{
      delimiter: '',
      complete: (result) => {
        if(result != undefined){
          console.log('Parsed: ', result);
        }
      }
    });
```

...It didn't papa parsed using ',' and not ';'. It couldn't detect ; as the delimiter.

If I convert all semi columns (;) into commas (,) and try to parse, than address field is splitted.

What is your suggestion?

Comment: Did you try setting `delimiter: ';'` explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

Set the delimiter explicitly instead of leaving it up to auto-detection.

```js
const csv_content = `name; address
Jack; 762 Texas Rd, Morganville NJ 07751 USA`;

Papa.parse(csv_content, {
  delimiter: ';',
  complete: (result) => {
    if (result != undefined) {
      console.log('Parsed: ', JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 2));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/4.6.2/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes I can do this, but than I need to force visitors to upload only using ";" as delimiter. Some programs export using many different delimiters.