# Separate each line of a text and process its information

Tags: javascript, node.js

I call some data in text file format from an API (https://en120.grepolis.com/data/players.txt). Each line in this text file is a single player with his information (name, ID, etc.). After every player is a line break. My current problem is I have no good strategy how to get each player separated and also call his specific information to push it into a new player object that will be saved in a json array.

Example:

first line in the text file (id, name, alliance_id, points, rank, towns)

```
6415107,Aragorn2,972,40297,461,4
```

should become to

```
{
  "id": 6415107,
  "name": "Aragorn2",
  "alliance_id": 972,
  "points": 40297,
  "rank": 461
  "towns": 4
}
```

#### In theory I could detect the first line break, take all characters from 0 to the position of the line break, remove this substring from the text file and process the data. But this feels really dowdy and I can imagine there is any good method with RegEx and `match`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a CSV string with Javascript, which contains comma in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow following method hope that will work

```js
var data=`6415107,Aragorn2,972,40340,462,4
6394106,BossLelei,,0,1534,0
5384599,stihls,,175,1514,1
6418914,newcastle,,0,1654,0
6394794,Harpocrates,762,0,1591,0`

lines=data.split("\n")
var result = [];
lines.forEach(x=>{
    let d=x.split(",");
    let o={};
    o["id"]=d[0];
    o["name"]=d[1];
    o["alliance_id"]=d[2];
    o["points"]=d[3];
    o["rank"]=d[4];
    o["towns"]=d[5];
    result.push(o)
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your conversion snippet. I will thoroughly study it to understand how it works. As against different csv parsers your code works.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a **npm module** for this scenario. With it will parse your csv-file to a JSON-Object in `nodeJS`. Checkout: https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser

With this it will build an `array` of `object` and will map the property name to the csv head line.

Example csv adjusted for your use case:

```
id, name, alliance_id, points, rank, towns
6415107,Aragorn2,972,40297,461,4
```

Comment: I like your idea and thanks for your tip that my file is a csv. I didnt even recognize it, ups. But I tested different csv parser and they had all a problem with the file. Finally @Sourabh Somanis answer converted the file correctly.