# Parsing CSV with regex

Tags: javascript, csv

I am trying to read below from CSV and split accordingly:

```
"1000";" ";"";;0;0;0;0
"1001";"tit;le1";"desc";0;0;0;0
"1002";"title2";"desc2";0;0;0;0
"1003";"title3";"desc123 desc23 desc2 de
sc34 dfd desc45 desc454;,

dfd desc desc";0;0;0;0
"1004";"tilte4";"desc5";0;0;0;0
```

I am using `[^;"][^"]+` and could get outcome of the strings between `" "` if not empty in above snippet.

I need the empty contents as well. Can you please help to correct the regex here `[^;"][^"]+`

Comment: May I suggest editing the title to better represent the actual problem?

Comment: Would it be possible to get a full-working, actual code-snippet?  This will make it easier to see the problem and to answer!  Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier for you to split every line with the separator ";" ?

Comment: Is using a ready-made JavaScript CSV-parser an option?

Comment: @felixjiricka No, because ";" can occur in a value, not only between values.

Comment: Yes, cannot use ";" as it occurs between strings as well.

Comment: I am reading csv file from nintex workflow and getting the strings between " " by using regular expression. I am testing my regular expression in url (https://regex101.com/r/mw03oC/2)

Comment: @UshaRamani Sometimes, a regex is not the solution. Please see [How can I parse a CSV string with JavaScript, which contains comma in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41563966/1115360) (you'll need to change the `','` to `';'`).

Comment: @AndrewMorton, why not? I think a regex is both possible and preferable.

Comment: @ByteEater If your regex is RFC 4180-compliant, it would be very useful if you added it as an answer in the Q&A I linked to.

Comment: It isn't. That RFC allows only for commas as separators. But otherwise I'll try to find time soon to look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the spec from my latest comment the right expression is `/(("?).*?\2)(;|$)/gsm`.

Comment: I included parentheses for grouping in the previous answer, assuming that you don't want the "s. Now I think you do, but the parentheses are needed for a different reason: your target with this expression is the 1st capturing group, not the whole match.

Comment: For completeness, a version stripping the "s from values:`/ ("?)(.*?)\1(;|$)/gs`, with capturing group 2.

Comment: This worked as well. I am actually trying to split as each row, but because i couldnt split as rows, i am now thinking to split as each string and then create a row item later. I think you might be able to help me with my actual problem , because if i can split as single row , it would save me a lot. I had posted another post for an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807334/regular-expression-to-split-strings-in-csv?noredirect=1#comment114583387_64807334. It would be great if you can help me here as well.

Comment: I've just noticed that there are no ;s at line ends, yet you want separation there (unless inside a string). So I edited the answer adding the `m` flag, so that e.g. `0` and `"1001"` aren't lumped together.

Comment: The question you linked is closed. Please edit it and apply for reopening or post yet another one which hopefully won't be closed. But specify your objective clearly, and preferably include the desired list of matches under the sample text.

Answer (score 0):

You want to get the stuff between ""? And there are no other " than those used as delimiters? Then `"(.*?)"` should work.

Comment: The same without a reluctant quantifier: `"([^"]*)"` or `"([^"]*).`.

Comment: Neither of the 3 expressions worked for me. I am trying in URL (https://regex101.com/r/mw03oC/2)

Comment: Did you enter them including the "s?

Comment: Oh, and if I understand correctly, there's a multiline string to be matched. In that case you should use the `s` flag with the expression. Thus: `/"(.*?)"/gs`.

Comment: tried this, but it doesnt capture the 0s and empty ex - ;;0;0;0;0 in the first line  and similarly in other lines all 0s.

Comment: Tried adding "(.*?)"|[^;"][^"]+ , except for the null/empty between ;; , everything seems to be now captured. i can split 0;0;0;0 further . but how to capture something between ;;

Comment: Then I didn't understand from you question what you wanted. So the ;s are separators, except when between "s, which always come in pairs and delimit strings – is that the complete specification? If so, see my new answer.

Comment: Thank you ByteEater. I have achieved with below regex  "(.*?)"|;;|[^;"][^"]+ . ; are seperators but i need anything in between ;; as it could be an empty one that need to be captured as a result.