# How to Convert Comma Separated String into an Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to skip double ; and omit last ; from string;

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "how;are;you;;doing;";
  var res = str.split(";");

  console.log(res[3]);
  console.log(res);
}

myFunction();
```

it should return `how,are,you,doing`

should be like `console.log(res[3])` = it should says `doing` not blank

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a CSV string with JavaScript, which contains comma in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```js
var str = "how;are;you;;doing;";

var filtered = str.split(";").filter(function(el) {
  return el != "";
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Output:

```
[ "how", "are", "you", "doing" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter empty strings after splitting:

```js
var str = "how;are;you;;doing;";

console.log(str.split(';').filter(Boolean));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```js
var a = "how;are;you;;doing;";
a = a.split(';').filter(element => element.length);

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below function definition is in ES6:

```
let myFunction = () => {
  let str = "how;are;you;;doing;";
  return str.split(';').filter((el) => {
    return el != "";
  });
}
```

Now you can simply log the output of the function call.

```
console.log(myFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use split for converting in an array, remove blank space and then join an array using sep",".

```
function myFunction(str) {
  var res = str.split(";");
  res = res.filter((i) => i !== "");
  console.log(res.join(","));
}

var str = "how;are;you;;doing;";
myFunction(str);
```