# How to parse a string in JavaScript based on comma as a delimiter?

Tags: javascript, string

Is there any way in JavaScript to parse a string?

For example, I have this string named "band":

```
let band = "John,Paul,George,Ringo";
```

and I want to parse it based on comma as a delimiter. So, in the end I want to have four variables:

```
let name1 = "John";
let name2 = "Paul";
let name3 = "George";
let name4 = "Ringo";
```

How can I do that?

Comment: For this type of thing it is better to use an array: `const names = band.split(',')`, and then access the values using an index: `names[0]`, etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a CSV string with JavaScript, which contains comma in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493195/how-can-i-parse-a-csv-string-with-javascript-which-contains-comma-in-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` the string on a comma:

```js
let band = "John,Paul,George,Ringo";
let members = band.split(',');
let john = members[0];
let paul = members[1];
let george = members[2];
let ringo = members[3];
```

This will give you an array called `members` which lets you access them using an index either directly or via a loop.

Depending on what browsers/environments you may need to support, you can destructure the array too:

```js
let band = "John,Paul,George,Ringo";
let [john, paul, george, ringo] = band.split(',');
```

If you want loop over the members:

```js
let band = "John,Paul,George,Ringo";
let members = band.split(',');

for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    console.log(members[i]);
}
```

This would loop over all members in the array and log them to console, which you can modify to perform other things on each item in the array.